# RxSwift Differ library crash `NSInternalInconsistencyException`

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I am trying to use `Diffing` with `RxSwift` in a basic example for now. I am using the [Differ](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Differ) library.

Here is my `Interactor` + `ViewModel`s associated:

```swift
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class Interactor {

    var items = [
            [1,5,6,7,4,6,7,1,5],
            [1,5,2,1,0,6,7],
    ]

    let viewModel: BehaviorRelay<ViewModel>

    var currentObjects: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            viewModel.accept(.init(with: .loaded(items[currentObjects])))
        }
    }

    init() {
        viewModel = BehaviorRelay(value: .init(with: .initialized))
    }

    func fetchValue() {
        currentObjects = currentObjects == 0 ? 1 : 0
    }


}

struct ViewModel {

    enum ViewModelType: Equatable {
        case cell(CellViewModel)
    }

    enum State {
        case initialized
        case loaded([Int])
    }

    let state: State
    let viewModels: [ViewModelType]

    init(with state: State) {
        self.state = state
        switch state {
        case .initialized: viewModels = []
        case .loaded(let values):
            viewModels = CellViewModel.from(values).map(ViewModelType.cell)
        }
    }
}

extension ViewModel: Equatable {

    static func ==(left: ViewModel, right: ViewModel) -> Bool {
        return left.state == left.state
    }
}

extension ViewModel.State: Equatable {

    static func ==(left: ViewModel.State, right: ViewModel.State) -> Bool {
        switch (left, right) {
        case (.initialized, .initialized): return true
        case let (.loaded(l), .loaded(r)): return l == r
        default: return false
        }
    }
}

struct CellViewModel {
    let description: String
}

extension CellViewModel {

    static func from(_ values: [Int]) -> [CellViewModel] {
        return values.map { CellViewModel(description: String($0)) }
    }
}

extension CellViewModel: Equatable {

    static func ==(left: CellViewModel, right: CellViewModel) -> Bool {
        return left.description == right.description
    }
}
```

Now for the view I am using a simple `UITableView

```swift
import UIKit
import Differ
import RxSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

        interactor
            .viewModel
            .asObservable()
            .scan([], accumulator: { (previous, current) in
              Array(previous + [current]).suffix(2)
            })
            .map({ (arr) -> (previous: ViewModel?, current: ViewModel) in
              (arr.count > 1 ? arr.first : nil, arr.last!)
            }).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (previous, current) in
                if let prev = previous {
                    print("Previous => State: \(prev.state) | ViewModelType.count: \(prev.viewModels.count)")
                } else {
                    print("Previous => State: nil | ViewModelType.count: nil")
                }
                print("Current => State: \(current.state) | ViewModelType.count: \(current.viewModels.count)")
                guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    strongSelf.tableView.animateRowChanges(oldData: previous?.viewModels ?? [], newData: current.viewModels)
                }
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        interactor.fetchValue()
    }

    @objc
    func onRefresh() {
        interactor.fetchValue()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return interactor.viewModel.value.viewModels.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellViewModel = interactor.viewModel.value.viewModels[indexPath.row]
        switch cellViewModel {
        case .cell(let viewModel):
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = viewModel.description
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

With everything conforming to Equatable, I thought the job would be done but I got an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` exception.

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (7 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

The prints I put to check what came from Rx before the crash show:

```
Previous => State: nil | ViewModelType.count: nil
Current => State: initialized | ViewModelType.count: 0
Previous => State: initialized | ViewModelType.count: 0
Current => State: loaded([1, 5, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7]) | ViewModelType.count: 7
```

The flow looks good to me in a logic stand point. Am I missing something?

---

## Edit 2019/10/29

I have made another version without using `RxSwift` to know if the problem was du to `RxSwift`:

```swift
protocol InteractorDelegate: class {
    func viewModelDidChange(_ old: ViewModel?, _ new: ViewModel)
}

class Interactor {

    weak var delegate: InteractorDelegate?

    var items = [
            [1,5,6,7,4,6,7,1,5],
            [1,5,2,1,0,6,7],
    ]

    var viewModel: ViewModel? {
        didSet {
            delegate?.viewModelDidChange(oldValue, viewModel!)
        }
    }

    var currentObjects: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            viewModel = .init(with: .loaded(items[currentObjects]))
        }
    }

    init() {
        viewModel = .init(with: .initialized)
    }

    func fetchValue() {
        currentObjects = currentObjects == 0 ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

For the `ViewController`:

```swift
extension ViewController: InteractorDelegate {

    func viewModelDidChange(_ old: ViewModel?, _ new: ViewModel) {

        if let prev = old {
            print("Previous => State: \(prev.state) | ViewModelType.count: \(prev.viewModels.count)")
        } else {
            print("Previous => State: nil | ViewModelType.count: nil")
        }
        print("Current => State: \(new.state) | ViewModelType.count: \(new.viewModels.count)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.animateRowChanges(oldData: old?.viewModels ?? [], newData: new.viewModels)
        }
    }
}
```

Seems that the issue is still same without `RxSwift`:

```
Previous => State: initialized | ViewModelType.count: 0
Current => State: loaded([1, 5, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7]) | ViewModelType.count: 7
2019-10-29 13:45:56.636678+0900 TestDiffer[93631:21379549] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (7 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Is there a problem with my `Equatable`s conformance?

---

## Edit 2019/10/29 #2

After new tests, I saw that the crash occurred only when the previous value is empty.

Everything is working fine with with changing the code like this:

```swift
extension ViewController: InteractorDelegate {

    func viewModelDidChange(_ old: ViewModel?, _ new: ViewModel) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard old != nil && !old!.viewModels.isEmpty else {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                return
            }
            self.tableView.animateRowChanges(oldData: old!.viewModels, newData: new.viewModels)
        }
    }
}
```

Same success when putting back RxSwift instead of the delegate.

Even if it is working as expected now. I am still questioning why the diffing isn't working when the array is empty. Having an previous value empty and a new value with 2 elements should be analyzed as 2 inserts no? What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you implemented the `RxTableViewDataSourceType` and passed it to the table view's `items` operator. An example project that does this is at: https://github.com/danielt1263/RxMultiCounter

I used DifferenceKit in my sample code so you will have to make some changes in the `tableView(_:observedEvent:)` method, but this should help point you in the right direction.

```
class RxSimpleAnimatableDataSource<E, Cell>: NSObject, 
    RxTableViewDataSourceType, 
    UITableViewDataSource 
    where E: Differentiable, Cell: UITableViewCell 
{
    typealias Element = [E]

    init(identifier: String, with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation = .automatic, configure: @escaping (Int, E, Cell) -> Void) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.animation = animation
        self.configure = configure
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, observedEvent: Event<Element>) {
        let source = values
        let target = observedEvent.element ?? []
        let changeset = StagedChangeset(source: source, target: target)
        tableView.reload(using: changeset, with: animation) { data in
            self.values = data
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
        let row = indexPath.row
        configure(row, values[row], cell)
        return cell
    }

    let identifier: String
    let animation: UITableView.RowAnimation
    let configure: (Int, E, Cell) -> Void
    var values: Element = []
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, appreciate your answer. I'll look into your approach. However I would like to know, if you have the answer, why is my approach not working before looking for other implementations to solve the problem.

Comment: Your `current.viewModels` isn't matching your `interactor.viewModel.value.viewModels`. Creating and using an `RxTableViewDataSourceType` will solve that problem.

Comment: In which way it isn't matching? I also edited the answer without using RxSwift at all. Seems that the issue is still the same.

Comment: Print the two values out and see how they aren't matching. You still have the problem because this isn't a problem with RxSwift, it's a problem with your logic. And it's a logic problem that's less likely to happen if you use an `RxTableViewDataSourceType`. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: I just found something interesting and have edited the question. I really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell what exactly is going on with just the code you posted here. Could you maybe provide a self-contained sample app showcasing the issue?

By the looks of the error message you are getting, I have faced a similar issue in the past. I believe this can happen if you don't use the API correctly and you schedule a transition before the `UITableView` had a chance to query its data source. I'm going to try to reproduce this issue in a sample app.

When the underlying data has changed, you call `animateRowChanges(oldData:newData:)`.
This diffs the data and determines where rows need to be inserted, deleted, and moved — in your case simply 7 insertions. `animateRowChanges(oldData:newData:)` then delegates to `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. In the scenario where the `UITableView` hasn't queried its data source before, `beginUpdates()` does just that and finds out that the `UITableView` is currently showing 7 rows. But after inserting 7 extra rows and calling `endUpdates()`, the data source still reports only 7 rows, hence the internal inconsistency exception.

---

Scheduling the transition when the underlying data *has already changed* is simply too late.
A `didSet` property observer or your method `viewModelDidChange(_:_:)` is not the place to do so. Really, scheduling the transition when the data has already changed is always wrong and only usually works because the `UITableView` caches its `numberOfSections` etc.

So how can you work around this issue?

The correct way to use these APIs is updating your data source between `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` or in the closure passed to `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`, not prior to these calls. The [`UICollectionView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates) also states that

> [i]f the collection view's layout is not up to date before you call this method, a reload may occur. To avoid problems, you should update your data model inside the updates block or ensure the layout is updated before you call `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`.

Differ supports this since [release 1.4.3](https://github.com/tonyarnold/Differ/releases/tag/1.4.3) in the form of an additional `updateData:` parameters on the `UICollectionView` family of the transitioning methods, but not on the `UITableView` family. I'm working on a pull request to bring this feature to `UITableView` as well.

Once that feature lands, you should be able to resolve your issue by changing the `viewModelDidChange(_:_:)` callback to something like `viewModelWillChange(from:to:updateData:)`. You should probably also make `var viewModel` a `private(set)` because as described above, the `didSet` property observer is too late to call these methods. Instead, you'll want to add a setter method that calls the delegate like so:

```
func setViewModel(_ newValue: ViewModel) {
    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate?.viewModelWillChange(from: viewModel, to: newValue, updateData: { self.viewModel = newValue })
    } else {
        self.viewModel = newValue
    }
}
```

Your implementation of `InteractorDelegate` could then look like so:

```
func viewModelWillChange(from oldValue: ViewModel?, to newValue: ViewModel, updateData: () -> Void) {
    self.tableView.animateRowChanges(oldData: oldValue.viewModels ?? [], newData: newValue.viewModels ?? [], updateData: updateData)
}
```

Alternatively, you can write a custom wrapper to `animateRowChanges(oldData:newData:)` today that checks if `oldData` is compatible with the current state of the `UITableView` by comparing to its `numberOfSections` and `numberOfItems(inSection:)`. If `oldData` is compatible, you can delegate to Differ, otherwise you could call `reloadData()`.